# supee 7405 Hunk #2 FAILED at 472. Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento, sh, patch, magento-1.8

I know how to install patches via shell, but this supee 7405 is giving me a problem.

The only error I get is
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 472.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED

I tried uploading the patched file, and then running the patch to update the rest of the files, but it still does not work..

No one else seems to have this issue with this file.
All previous patches are applied

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Make sure you have installed SUPEE-6285. Check app/etc/applied.patches.list and apply ALL missing previous security patches in the order in which they were released. Hunk failures are caused by code mismatches from 1) Modified core files, 2) Core files that got corrupted on upload (added spaces, line ending translation failure, etc.) and 3) missing previous patches. All cause file content mismatch when `patch` attempts to find the original content and refresh it to the new content which is known as a hunk failure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply your patch manually for this file.

1- Copy and save the lines refering to the lines refering to the file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

2- Inside the patch file, remove the lines refering to the file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

3- Apply your patch

4- Open file the file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php and modify the lines you saved at the first step